# Is this a resource leak or a false positive?

Tags: java

Eclipse gives me a warning on the declaration of "out". Is this a false positive?

```
Random r = new Random();
try(PrintWriter out1 = new PrintWriter("one.txt");
    PrintWriter out2 = new PrintWriter("two.txt"))
{
  PrintWriter out = r.nextBoolean()?out1:out2;
  out.println("x");
}
```

P.S.: The warning is "*Resource leak: 'out' is never closed*".

Comment: Should be not closed after use.

Comment: Seems to be **false positive**. BTW `Idea` doesn't give any warning on that line.

Comment: Could be a false positive, since this is rather new.

Comment: It's a false positive. Eliminating it would be a PITA, I imagine.

Comment: which IDE are you using? Indigo Service Release 2 is not giving me any warning about this

Comment: I am using Eclipse Juno and Java 7 OpenJDK.

Answer (score 5):

It's a false positive. All instances are correctly closed.

I turned off those resource-related warnings in Eclipse long ago. They're really not reliable as there are so many "obviously" correct control flow paths that cannot be identified as "correct" by Eclipse without actually executing them... Any non-trivial code will be doomed to have those false positives.

Answer (score 1):

**It is definitely false positive**, `out` is being assigned `out1` or `out2` which is being automatically closed. Furthermore out is not visible outside try block.

Comment: The "non-visibility" outside of the try block is precisely what is causing Eclipse to assess that a potential resource leak is at hand. I.e. within the scope of the `out` variable, it is never closed...